# Batch to add current datetime to filename

Tags: batch, rename

I would like to add the current datetime to all filenames in the current directory.

I think this can be done with batch/xcopy like:

`xcopy /s /x c:\xxx\*.* c:\yyy\*%datetime%.*`

@RockPaperLz: thanks for your response, it is not working, only the filename has to be changed and not filename plus file extension.

It's needed to only add timestamp to current filename.

Thank you very much for your help!